# Find a point on a line knowing it's y coordinate

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

How can I find the x coordinate of point C in this diagram, where A, B and l are known?

[image: Diagram of problem]

Comment: Besides knowing $\;A,B\;$ you must know more: what's the distance of $\;A\;$ or $\;B\;$ from $\;C\;$ , or the ratio $\;\frac{AC}{BC}\;$

Comment: @Timbuc l is the distance along the y axis to C, but I don't know C's x coordinate.  That's what I need to find out.

Comment: If you know the y-coordinate of C and you know A and B, why don't you find the equation of the line. And Then use the y-coordinate of C to find the x coordinate of C.

Comment: @randomgirl Heh. You're right.  I wasn't even thinking in that direction.  Thanks.  If you want to write up an answer I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the two-point form:
$$\frac{y_c-y_a}{y_a-y_b}=\frac{x_c-x_a}{x_a-x_b}$$
And the fact that $$y_a-y_c=l$$
So:
$$x_c=x_a-\frac{x_a-x_b}{y_a-y_b}l$$